# @ Variables empty in Gherkins/Cucumber test

Tags: ruby, cucumber

This is my test, but even though @timeout_exception is working during running of the code, it's empty during the test. So how can I test if this variable is set?

```
Then(/^the output should be '(.*)'$/) do |expectedException|
  expect(@timeout_exception).to eq(expectedException)
end
```

This is the output of the bundle exec cucumber run.

```
And the output should be 'Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run'                                     # features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:309

  expected: "Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run"
       got: nil

  (compared using ==)
   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:310:in `/^the output should be '(.*)'$/'
  features/timeout_lengthy_deploys.feature:25:in `And the output should be 'Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run''

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/timeout_lengthy_deploys.feature:11 # Scenario: Normal deploy that times out because it takes too long
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has its own waits and if they are set less than your expected wait then you will never see your expected wait triggered.  Make sense?

The following sets the max wait for page load to 5 seconds

```
@browser.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 5
```

Script timeout is another (generally used with Ajax)

```
@browser.driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 5
@browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
```

Implicit Wait is the maximum wait time for Selenium to wait for an operation on an element to complete. If this triggers first then your expect will fail.

```
@browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5
```

I would suggest setting implicit_wait higher than your timeout just prior to the test and then setting it back just afterwards.  BTW, if your timeout raises an exception you will need a rescue block.